# How to pass dataframe columns as argument when curlycurly does not work? (e.g.map function within nest)

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr, rlang

I'm very happy that it is relatively easy to pass dataframe columns as function argument with "curly curly" `{{}}` to e.g. filter() or select(). But this does not work with nest and map (see code below, **{{x}}** in lm function) and I don't know why. How do you proceed in this case?

I have the following code which I would like to run for several variables (and not only for var1 e.g. as here in the example):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

var1 <- runif(100)
var2 <- rnorm(100)
var3 <- rnorm(100,mean=3)
group <- c(rep(1,25),rep(2,25),rep(3,25),rep(4,25))

data_set <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3,group)

nest_fct <- function(x){
  new <- data_set %>%
    filter(is.na({{x}}) != 1) %>% 
    select({{x}}, var2, group ) %>%
    nest(data = -group) %>% 
    mutate(
      fit = map(data,   ~ lm({{x}} ~  var2, data = .)),
      tidied = map(fit, tidy)) %>% 
    unnest(tidied) %>% 
    select(-data, -fit)
}
new <- nest_fct(var1)
```

I get the error (sorry that it is in German):  Fehler: Problem with `mutate()` input `fit`.
x Variablenlängen sind unterschiedlich (gefunden für 'var2')
i Input `fit` is `map(data, ~lm(var1 ~ var2, data = .))`.

(I want to run a regression for each group and then save the regression coefficients)

The code runs through without the function "nest_fct":

```
new <- data_set %>%
  filter(is.na(var1) != 1) %>% 
  select(var1, var2, group ) %>%
  nest(data = -group) %>% 
  mutate(
    fit = map(data,   ~ lm(var1 ~  var2, data = .)),
    tidied = map(fit, tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(tidied) %>% 
  select(-data, -fit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method with `exexpr/expr`

```
nest_fct <- function(x){
  new <- data_set %>%
    filter(is.na({{x}}) != 1) %>% 
    select({{x}}, var2, group ) %>%
    nest(data = -group) %>% 
    mutate(
      fit = map(data,   ~ lm(rlang::expr(!! rlang::enexpr(x) ~ var2), data = .)),
      tidied = map(fit, tidy)) %>% 
    unnest(tidied) %>% 
    select(-data, -fit)
}
new <- nest_fct(var1)


new
# A tibble: 8 x 6
#  group term        estimate std.error statistic       p.value
#  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
#1     1 (Intercept)  0.475      0.0543    8.75   0.00000000896
#2     1 var2        -0.0250     0.0492   -0.507  0.617        
#3     2 (Intercept)  0.468      0.0544    8.60   0.0000000122 
#4     2 var2         0.0617     0.0495    1.25   0.225        
#5     3 (Intercept)  0.572      0.0616    9.29   0.00000000301
#6     3 var2         0.00304    0.0559    0.0544 0.957        
#7     4 (Intercept)  0.476      0.0575    8.29   0.0000000234 
#8     4 var2         0.180      0.0576    3.13   0.00473
```